# How to resolve "gpg: command not found" error during RVM installation?

Tags: ruby, macos, command-line, rvm, gnupg

I have a new mac pro (OS X 10.9.5) that I get to set up from scratch. I want to install RVM and the first thing it says to do is:

> Install mpapis public key (might need `gpg2` and or `sudo`)
>
> ```
> gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3
> ```

When I tried I got:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3
zsh: command not found: gpg
```

I've tried to find a good guide on how to overcome this that also looks trustworthy but I've had no luck.

Can someone explain what `gpg` is, why I don't already have it, and how do I get it the right way.

Comment: did you try "gpg" in Google? It's public key encryption, and you need to install the appropriate tool either by hand or from Brew or Macports. Also not exactly a StackOverflow question.

Comment: Hi guys, if you are trying to set up RVM in 2021 or later and found this issue, after you installed by brew and run the command on RVM again, you will see "gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name" error, that's because the SKS Keyserver Network is being deprecated. You need to change the keyserver to another one, like run "gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB". From <https://stackoverflow.com/a/68132500>.

Answer (score 354, accepted):

**GnuPG** (with binary name `gpg`) is an application used for public key encryption using the OpenPGP protocol, but also **verification of signatures** (cryptographic signatures, that also can **validate the publisher** if used correctly). To some extend, you could say it's for OpenPGP what OpenSSL is for X.509 and TLS.

Unlike most Linux distributions (which make heavy use of GnuPG for ensuring untampered software within their package repositories), Mac OS X does not bring GnuPG with the operating system, so you **have to install it on your own**.

Possible sources are:

- Package manager [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/): `brew install gnupg gnupg2`
- Package manager [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/): `sudo port install gnupg gnupg2`
- Install from [GPGTools](https://gpgtools.org/), which also brings GUI applications and integration in Apple Mail

Comment: I had the exact same issue as the original question asked by JDillon522. To install RVM I only installed `gpg2`. This answer helped me to additionally install `gpg`.

Comment: brew install gnupg gnupg2 -> Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink share/man/man8/addgnupghome.8
/usr/local/share/man/man8 is not writable.

Comment: This sounds like some other package/package manager changed permissions for that folder. `brew doctor` might indicate the problem and suggest solutions, but generally I'd rather ask for help at Ask Different, using a package manager is rather off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Installing via homebrew didn't seem to work for me. Despite the process completing without a problem the gpg command was still unavailable. I ended up using gpg tools which made the command available.

Comment: I guess that something wrent wrong setting up your `$PATH` variable.

Comment: how to install gnupg gnupg2 on **windows** as brew installer is for mac only?

Comment: You're probably best off with the [GPG4Win distribution](https://www.gpg4win.org/) of GnuPG, which also includes an installer. If you still have issues with `gpg` not being found, make sure your `%PATH%` variable is set up properly.

Comment: brew doctor worked to help me get it working after I was getting the gpg command not found.

Answer (score 35):

As the instruction said `"might need gpg2"`

In mac, you can try install it with homebrew

```
$ brew install gpg2
```

Comment: If you don't have homebrew, you can install it on Mac OS X with the command:  `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"` See (http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/installing-homebrew-os-x-yosemite-10-10-package-manager-unix-apps/) for more information.

Comment: A user will also need to install `gpg` in addition to `gpg2`, see the answer by Jens Erat.

Answer (score 26):

On Mac OSX 10.15,
Even after installing gpg, i was getting gpg2 command not found

```
$ brew install gnupg gnupg2
Warning: gnupg 2.2.23 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 2.2.23, run `brew reinstall gnupg`

$ gpg2 --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
-bash: gpg2: command not found
```

Instead, this worked for me

```
$ gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
```

Comment: Seconding that running with `keyserver` flag worked!

Comment: Got 'gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name' with command as given.  Tried a different keyserver and worked.

Comment: Yep, first 2 key servers from sks-keyservers.net don't work for me now. 3rd one from https://rvm.io/rvm/security worked: `gpg --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB`

Comment: Had the same problem and the gpg one worked!

Answer (score 12):

Here are the steps to install RVM.

**Step 1: Install gpg or gpg2 (both work)**

```sh
brew install gpg
```

**Step 2: Install GPG keys used to verify installation package:**

```sh
gpg --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
```

If you encounter problem with the key server above, try a different one.

- hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net
- hkp://pgp.mit.edu
- hkp://keyserver.pgp.com

**Step 3: Install RVM**

```sh
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Check out the [Security](http://rvm.io/rvm/security) page if you still run into problems.

Comment: gpg: keyserver receive failed: No keyserver available

Answer (score 7):

[This](http://brewformulas.org/Gnupg) worked for me

```
$brew install gnupg
```

Answer (score 2):

After installing gpg using:

```
brew install gnupg2
```

This solution helped me get the keys to install rvm:

```
curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg --import -
curl -sSL https://rvm.io/pkuczynski.asc | gpg --import -
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue when I was trying to install **RVM** on a **UNIX Apple M1**.

I can solved my issue with this command:

```
gpg --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
```

Instead of use `gpg2`:

```
gpg2 --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
```

After run the command I had this output:

```bash
gpg: key 195BD3E759199BDB: 1 duplicate signature removed
gpg: /Users/User/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 105BD0E739499BDB: public key "Piotr Kuczynski <piotr.kuczynski@gmail.com>" imported
gpg: key 3804BB82D39DC0E3: public key "Michal Papis (RVM signing) <mpapis@gmail.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 2
gpg:               imported: 2
```

**Note:**
Don't forget to restart your command console.

Answer (score 0):

On my clean macOS 10.15.7, I needed to `brew link gnupg && brew unlink gnupg` first and then used Ashish's answer to use `gpg` instead of `gpg2`. I also had to `chown` a few directories. before the un/link.

Answer (score -12):

You can also use:

```
$ sudo gem install rvm
```

It should give you the following output:

```
Fetching: rvm-1.11.3.9.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rvm-1.11.3.9
Parsing documentation for rvm-1.11.3.9
Installing ri documentation for rvm-1.11.3.9
1 gem installed
```