# gnupg2 not found and reinstall was not useful for mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, homebrew, rvm

I'm trying to install [rvm](https://rvm.io/) for mac.But I already install gnupg/gnupg2.

```
 brew install gnupg2
```

> Warning: gnupg 2.2.21 is already installed and up-to-date,To reinstall 2.2.21,run 'brew reinstall gnupg'

And I used command

```
 gpg2 --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
```

> zsh: command not found: gpg2

Can someone help me answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to install `gnupg` in addition to `gnupg2`

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27042267/4701098

Comment: First I was using `brew install gnupg gnupg2` already.
I thought there was't need to use two  protocols.
So I just use gpg2.
But I can't solve this problem either.
Same problem is "zsh: command not found: gpg2".